# Quais são as tabelas de produtos do Woocommerce?

Tags: banco-de-dados, wordpress, woocommerce

Estou pensando em fazer uma integração entre *Magento e Wordpress* e gostaria de saber se alguém tem ideia de quais são as tabelas responsáveis pelos produtos no WordPress com o plugin do **Woocommerce**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas são as tabelas criadas pelo WooCommerce:

- wp_woocommerce_api_keys
- wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies
- wp_woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions
- wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
- wp_woocommerce_order_items
- wp_woocommerce_sessions wp_woocommerce_tax_rates
- wp_woocommerce_tax_rate_locations
- wp_woocommerce_termmeta

Mas ele também inseri informações na:

- wp_postmeta